# C3D + LSTM for video classification

Tags: python, keras

I want to use C3D model followed by lstm to train UCF101 for video classification using keras.
I have reshaped the video to be [None, 16, 112, 112,3]. I have used time distributed keras function in C3D but yet I still did not get what should the input shape for this model, the output shape, and the time steps number. could  anyone help me in this issue. 
thanks

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv3D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1', input_shape=shape)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2,2), strides=(1,2,2), padding='same', name='pool1')))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv3D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), strides=(2,2,2), padding='valid', name='pool2')))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv3D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3a')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv3D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3b')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), strides=(2,2,2), padding='valid', name='pool3')))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv3D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4a')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv3D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4b')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), strides=(2,2,2), padding='valid', name='pool4')))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv3D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5a')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv3D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5b')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(ZeroPadding3D(padding=(0,1,1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), strides=(2,2,2), padding='valid', name='pool5')))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc6')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc7')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(487, activation='softmax', name='fc8')))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, dropout = 0.5, input_shape = (time_step_nbr, 487)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(101, activation='softmax')))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3d CNN works with the videos, MRI, and scan datasets. If you have to feed the input (video) to the proposed 3d CNN network, and train it's weights, as 3d CNN expect 5 dimensional inputs;

```
[batch size, channels, depth, height, weight]
```

Lets Suppose;
If you have 10 video of 10 different classes. The duration of each video is 6 seconds, and you extract 2 frames for each second and it goes around 12 frames for each video.

Size of RGB videos are 112x112 --> Height = 112, Width=112, and Channels=3

If you keep the batch size equals 2

1 video --> 6 seconds --> 12 frames (1sec == 2frames) [each frame (3,112,112)]

10 videos (10 classes) --> 60 seconds --> 120 frames

So the 5 dimensions will be something like this; [2, 3, 12, 112, 112]

2 --> Two videos will be processed for each batch size.

3 --> RGB channels

12 --> each video contains 12 frames

112 --> Height of each video

112 --> Width of each video

this way you can give input to the 3d CNN, there might be many other ways as well.